# Add a dot after a number in R

Tags: r, format, decimal

I have the following list `c(1.23,1,0.9)` which Shows in the console`[1] 1.23 1 0.9`  , I would like to transform it to:
`[1] 1.23,1.,.9` .
As you can see the first numebr remains the same but 1 become 1. and 0.9 become .9.

Is there is an elegant way to have this Format ?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a matter of printing, or representations.

What you might want to do is transform it as a character:

```
res <- as.character(c(1.23,1,0.9))
```

And then use regexp:

```
res <- gsub("^0", "", res) # delete leading 0s
res[!grepl("\\.", res)] <- paste0(res[!grepl("\\.", res)], ".") # Add a "." at the end where there are no 0s
```

And the result is:

```
res
[1] "1.23" "1."   ".9"
```

Comment: He could create an S3 class and use this approach for a printing method. He could then set `quote = FALSE` within `print.default` and thereby avoid the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method with `sprintf` and `gsub`:

```
gsub("0", "", sprintf("%.2f", x))
[1] "1.23" "1."   ".9"
```

To add the commas you could place this in a `paste` function.

```
paste(gsub("0", "", sprintf("%.2f", x)), collapse=",")
[1] "1.23,1.,.9"
```